# Can I change a ubuntu partition from sdb to sda?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, grub

I have just gotten into Ubuntu and I'm not quite familiar with partitions etc. But I have Ubuntu installed on `/dev/sdb`. But I want to move it to `/dev/sda`. Current partition listing below. Can I just move it and keep documents etc. to?

**/dev/sda**:

```
Unallocated 931 GB
```

**/dev/sdb**:

```
/dev/sdb1 ext4 Mount=/ 21.42 GB
/dev/sdb2 linux-swap 100 MB
Unallocated 854 MB
/dev/sdb3 unknown 1 MB (This is grub)
Unallocated 12.96 MB
```

Comment: Is your /dev/sdb really only about 22 GB in size total?

Comment: But yes; I don't have time to write up a proper answer detailing how to do it, and it might be a duplicate, but it is possible to move a Linux installation from one physical disk to another. I've done it several times. It's a little involved, but it's definitely doable. Or you can move only certain parts of the system (like, say, /home) to a second drive and keep the OS where it is (which is easier). If it just bothers you that your stuff is on /dev/sdb rather than /dev/sda (the names, not the drives), then don't worry about it; you almost never will concern yourself with those.

Comment: I was going to post this as an answer but I don't think it is what you really want to do.  -- If you want to switch how they show up you can power down the machine, and switch the drives around.  so that the one that was plugged into the sda spot is plugged into the sdb spot and the sdb is plugged into the sda spot.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it, see questions [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151127/how-do-i-move-copy-my-entire-ubuntu-system-to-a-different-hard-disk) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/106527/how-to-move-ubuntu-installation-from-one-hdd-to-another)

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want to switch **names**? Or do you want to transfer content from sdb to sda? BTW, sda, sdb are devices, not partitions. sdb1, sdb2, sdb3 are partitions.